# XMLHttpRequest cannot load.No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i want to signin to a website by sending url,username and password but that sending an error like above  XMLHttpRequest cannot load `https://example.org`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed access..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>build</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
            {
                document.getElementById("test1").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
            } else
                {
                     alert('Panel not communicating.Reason: '+xmlhttp.status);
                }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/xyz/xyz.git",true,"username","password");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");
        xmlhttp.send();

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

any one please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" policy is a security manner used in cross domain HTTP requests.
It's idea is to net let "everyone" pull data from your server in order to keep the data safe.
you can read more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS .

Comment: thanks @Aviad , but  it given an security error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next/xyz/xyz.git. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS." how can i solve it.